# Bpy: Alpha mode not updating for bake and save

Tags: python, image, texture-baking, baking

The code below, I am trying to save an image who's alpha mode was set to 'STRAIGHT' then immediately changed to 'NONE', however, I am only getting the straight result when this is completed(See resulting images in image at bottom of this post). image.update() and image.reload() have not resolved this for me testing before, inbetween, and after the bake and save. If manually changed, the texture will first update in the 3d viewport and not update in the UV/Image editor until you've re-entered it. Thanks for the help.

```
import bpy
import os

obj=bpy.context.active_object
mat=obj.active_material
if obj is None or mat is None:
    return
nodes=mat.node_tree.nodes
image_node=nodes.active
if image_node is None or image_node.type!='TEX_IMAGE':
    return
image=image_node.image
image.source='GENERATED'

image.alpha_mode='STRAIGHT'
image.alpha_mode='NONE'

# Bake a diffuse map
bpy.ops.object.bake(type='DIFFUSE')
image.update()

image_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads"), "alpha_test.png")
image.filepath_raw = image_path
image.save()
```

[image]